# How can I import external data into HealthKit?

Tags: ios, import, health.app, health-kit

I have a few apps that may not be updated to support iOS 8 and HealthKit, but they do offer CSV export of data they have stored.

Is there any way to import historical data into HealthKit and Health.app?

Comment: Brian, would it be possible to be able to import data from a Cpap machine in the form of a CSV file into health kit under sleep category? i am currently using a Resmed S9 Cpap machine and am able to take my sleep data from the machine and export the data to a CSV file using an open source program by the name of Sleepyhead. i would really like to be able to import this data into the health kit app. i see your companies app Health Importer would be a great choice and i would love to buy the app however with out this function doesn't do me much good. i can provide more information and the cvs fil

Comment: Jeff - the Apple approach to handling sleep data is very different than what most people would track and how most cpap's handle the data.  To date, we've not seen a data set that has the necessary information that Apple wants for the data type, but I'd be happy to take a look at yours and see if it would work.  Please email me a sample of your data and I can take a look.  You can send it to support [at] paradox-customs.com.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Third party developers can provide import functionality to health app via the normal Health Kit API on iOS.

Some apps scrape or use web API such as [Sync Solver](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sync-solver-for-fitbit/id935306292?mt=8) exist to get FitBit data from the cloud to the local health app on iOS. 
Some such as [Health Importer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/health-importer/id930943780?ls=1&mt=8) are more general. *(proper disclosure: **I work on this app**)*

We have an app on the store that is designed specifically for importing arbitrary CSV data into HealthKit / Health.App.

Here are a few screenshots from the development version to show how the app works:

CSV's can be sent via email and then opened in the app:

[image: Waiting for CSV import]

[image: Open in app]

You can then configure each of the columns within your CSV to a supported data type from HealthKit / Health.App:

[image: Ready for import]

After that, just tap the import button and it'll bring the data in:

[image: Importing data]

[image: Import complete]

Comment: Someone sent you a message as a new answer, and whoever converted it to a comment put it on my question by accident...

Comment: Health Importer seems to be very buggy. It does't work very well.

Comment: Doesn't work in iOS 9 at all. Pathetic that we can't import Apple's own health data!

Comment: With almost 2000 copies installed, the app is working very well for a large number of people.  We have a few bugs that we're aware of and are working on a solution for.  Development on the app was halted for a number of months while moving across the country and then bringing it up-to-date with Apple's latest sdks, but we're back at it and working on a new release.  We have confirmed it is working well in iOS9 and one of our updates that we're working on is for support of Apple's own exports from Health.app.

Comment: Can this app import a folder full of csv files, in the same format that Google Fit exports? I've switched from Android to iPhone, and exported my Google Fit data using Google Takeout. Does your app import that?

Comment: As of April 2020, the App Store says Health Importer is not available (at least in the U.S.). I was able to import weight data using Health CSV Importer linked to in the answer from @Rachel.

Answer (score 2):

*Lionheart Software* actually just released an app called [Health CSV Importer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/health-csv-importer/id1275959806?mt=8) that does exactly this. Essentially, it takes pretty much any CSV you could throw at it, and pulls it into Apple Health.

Lionheart also has an app called [Health Data Importer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/health-data-importer/id1158733998?mt=8) that transfers data from an old iPhone to a new one (without having to restore that phone from a backup).
`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the built in iOS shortcuts app.

Here's a [template](https://bit.ly/glucoseimport) that allows you to pick a csv file from iCloud. Right now, it's set up to use a CSV where the first column is the Date and then the last column is a glucose measurement.

If you're willing to tinker a bit, you may only need to modify it in a couple spots so that it works with your data.